# SPIA package (R) applied to Illumina expression microarray data

Tags: r, package

I've been experimenting with alternative annotation to GSEA for expression (mRNA)data. 
SPIA (Signalling Pathway Integration Analysis) looks interesting, but it seems to have exactly one error message for everything:

```
Error in spia(de = sigGenes, all = allGenes, organism = "hsa", plots = TRUE,  :  
de must be a vector of log2 fold changes. The names of de should >be     
included in the reference array!
```

The input requires a single vector of log2 fold changes(my vector is named sigGenes), with Entrez ID as the associated names, and an integer vector of Entrez IDs included in the microarray (allGenes):

```
head(sigGenes)
6144 115286  23530  10776  83933   6232 
0.368  0.301  0.106  0.234 -0.214  0.591 
head(allGenes)
6144 115286  23530  10776  83933   6232
```

I've already removed values whose EntrezID annotations that are NA. 
I've also subset my data from the Illumina microarray to only those genes found in the Affymetrix array using the example provided in the site I list below. I still get the same error.

Here is the full bit of R code:

```
library(Biobase)
library(limma)
library(SPIA)

sigGenes <- subset(full_table, P.Value<0.01)$logFC
names(sigGenes) <- subset(full_table, P.Value<0.01)$EntrezID
sigGenes<-sigGenes[!is.na(names(sigGenes))] # remove NAs

allGenes <- unique(full_table$EntrezID[!is.na(full_table$EntrezID)])

spiaOut <- spia(de=sigGenes, all=allGenes, organism="hsa", plots=TRUE, data.dir="./")
```

Any ideas of what else I could try?
Apologies if off topic (still new here). Happy to move the question elsewhere if needed.

Example of SPIA applied to Affymetrix platform data here: http://www.gettinggeneticsdone.com/2012/03/pathway-analysis-for-high-throughput.html)

Comment: what's the output of `setdiff(names(sigGenes),allGenes)` ?

Comment: setdiff gives a vector of length 20707.         

`head(setdiff(allGenes,names(sigGenes)))`  
51074  51006 728927   4543 257415   2730  

`setdiff(names(sigGenes), allGenes)` gives character(0)

Comment: Ok, what about: `length(intersect(names(sigGenes), allGenes)) != length(sigGenes)` ? that seems to be the condition where spia throws the error.

Comment: That gave me a TRUE.
Looking at it further I think the problem is that there are duplicate entries.
length(sigGenes)=355; length(intersect(names(sigGenes), allGenes)) =337;
length(unique(names(sigGenes)))=337
Trying out some code to see if this is the reason. Will post update shortly. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on our discussion I would suggest removing duplicated entries in `sigGenes`. Without additional information, it is hard to say where the duplicates might originate from, and which one to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the duplicates did help. 
As a workaround, I chose the median value (only because the values were close) among each set of duplicates as follows:

```
dups<-unique(names(sigGenes[which(duplicated(names(sigGenes)))])) # determine which are duplicates
dupID<-names(sigGenes) %in% dups # determine the laocation of all duplicates
sigGenes_dup<-vector(); j=0; # determine the median value for each duplicate
for (i in dups){j=j+1; sigGenes_dup[j]<- median(sigGenes[names(sigGenes)==i])  }
names(sigGenes_dup)<-dups
sigGenes<-sigGenes[!(names(sigGenes) %in% dups)] # remove duplicates from sigGenes
sigGenes<-c(sigGenes,sigGenes_dup) # append the median values of the duplicates
```

Alternatively just removing the duplicates works:

```
dups<-unique(names(sigGenes[which(duplicated(names(sigGenes)))]))
sigGenes<-sigGenes[!(names(sigGenes) %in% dups)] # remove duplicates from sigGenes
```